# UITextView Clickable link sensitive to trigger(if touch start on that link) action on iOS13

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

I set the clickable link to `UITextView` by setting `NSAttributedString` **`.link`** type.

on iOS 13, if the user starts to touch the clickable part will trigger the `UITextView` Delegate Method(**instead of touchUpInside**).

on the lower iOS version, user touchUpInside will trigger the Delegate which is right

I write an easy demo to reproduce this issue, Please check this repo https://github.com/RandallWang/iOS13TextViewDemo

=============

Update: This seems like an iOS 13 bug, On apple Podcasts, every link in Episode Notes have the same issue

=============

Update: iOS 13.2 fix this bug

Comment: you should rephrase your question, what `too sensitive` means?

Comment: @Lu_ Thanks, I have updated my question, please check the Demo I attached

Comment: I still don't know what `too sensitiv` means, what exactly you want to happen instead of opening url? where is your touchUpInside code in this example?

Comment: In the previous iOS version, .link attributed string in TextView work like a button. Which means the user touch the link and the finger move up inside the link's bounds, this touchUpInside action will call the delegate method(func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool).


But in iOS 13, the delegate method will be called the moment you touch starts at the link

Comment: facing the same issue on iOS 13

Comment: me too, anyone with any ideas ?

Comment: Same here, driving me mad atm